# How to fix the Segmentation fault (core dumped) in C++?

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

I'm writing a program that combines 2 vectors and sorts them and then prints the vector but I'm not using a third vector. Instead I'm combining one vector with another and then sorting the combined vector. But I get a error called "Segmentation fault".

here's the code:

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    // your code goes here
    ios_base::sync_with_stdio(0);
    cin.tie(0);
    int m,n; 
    cin >> m >> n;
    vector<int> nums1, nums2;
    for(int i=0; i<m; i++) cin >> nums1[i];
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++) cin >> nums2[i];
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){ // nums2 
        nums1.push_back(nums2[i]); // I am adding all the elements present in nums2 into nums1
    }
    sort(nums1.begin(), nums1.end());
    for(int i=0; i<(m+n); i++) cout << nums1[i] << " ";
    return 0;
}
```

The error I get: run: line 1:     3 Segmentation fault      (core dumped) LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/gcc-8.3.0/lib64 ./a.out

Please tell me how I can fix this error and how I could avoid it in the future.

Comment: Both `nums1` and `nums2` are empty after you create them, so you cannot index into them (with `cin >> nums1[i];`)

Comment: @UnholySheep how do I fix this then?

Comment: Use the correct constructor for a vector. Constructor 4) from : https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector and nums1.push_back(nums2[i]); can be replaced with a call to insert : https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/insert

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here:

```
vector<int> nums1, nums2;

for(int i=0; i<m; i++) cin >> nums1[i]; // this causes undefined behavior
for(int i=0; i<n; i++) cin >> nums2[i]; // also this one
```

your vectors have no buffer to store data so you need to do this before using `operator[]`:

```
vector<int> nums1(m), nums2(n);

nums1.push_back(2); // will add 2 to the back of nums1 so size will become m + 1
nums2.push_back(6); // will add 6 to the back of nums2 so size will become n + 1

// you can do as many push_backs as you want until
// your computer runs out of memory
```

Now both will be initialized with `m` and `n` number of elements respectively.

If you used the `at` function instead of `[]`, the program would throw a `std::out_of_range` exception and you would suddenly notice that you were trying to go out of bounds. But of course `at` comes at a performance cost.

Comment: a question, is it possible for me to input more than 'm' or 'n' number of elements into nums1 and nums2 respectively or am I restricted to m and n no.of elements in the respective vectors kinda like arrays?

Comment: @NerdNet Check the updated answer.